# How gdb locate the address of local variable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

there is short program, the code is just as follow:

```
/* init.c */
#include <syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int pid, exitstatus;
    char shell[] = "shell";
    char * args[] = {shell, 0}; 

    while(1) {
        pid = fork();
        if (!pid)
            exec(shell, args);

        while (pid != wait(&exitstatus));

        printf("Shell exited with status %d; starting it back up...", exitstatus);
    }
}
```

compiled using gcc:

```
gcc -nostdinc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin -Wall -gstabs -Werror -O0 -m32 -c -o init.o init.c
```

using objdump to check the gstabs information of variable pid:

```
objdump -G init.o | grep pid
```

and the output of objdump:

```
37 LSYM 0 0 00000018 777 pid:(0,1)
```

When I try to print the memory address of pid within gdb:

```
print &pid
```

the result shows that &pid == $ebp + 0x18, but the assembly code is actually operate at memory address $esp + 0x18 as the assembly code will show below.

part of the disassemble output of init.o:

```
20 2c: c7 44 24 20 00 00 00     movl $0x0,0x20(%esp)
21 33: 00
22 34: e8 fc ff ff ff           call 35 <main+0x35>
23 39: 89 44 24 18              mov %eax,0x18(%esp)
24 3d: 83 7c 24 18 00           cmpl $0x0,0x18(%esp)
25 42: 75 16                    jne 5a <main+0x5a>
26 44: 8d 44 24 1c              lea 0x1c(%esp),%eax
27 48: 89 44 24 04              mov %eax,0x4(%esp)
28 4c: 8d 44 24 26              lea 0x26(%esp),%eax
```

here at line 23：

```
mov %eax,0x18(%esp)
```

I think that what this instruction does is storing the result of fork() to variable  pid,  and it's using the address $esp + 0x18 not $ebp + 0x18 as gdb shows, as result, I can not get the desired result when I execute print pid in gdb (so as other local variables). So, how could this happen?

Comment: Don't use stabs.  They are old and basically unmaintained, both in gdb and in gcc.  I wouldn't be surprised at any bugs occurring with stabs.  If the problem persists with DWARF, update your post & we can figure it out.

Comment: @TomTromey after changing -gstabs to -gdwarf-4, the problem disappears, namely I can now see the correct value of local variables under gdb,  perhaps stabs is the real cause of the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us what version of gcc are you using, and what target? I don't think I've ever seen 32-bit x86 gcc generate offsets from esp rather than ebp for locals, unless the compiler was passed `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick gcc Target: x86_64-linux-gnu, --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1', no -fomit-frame-pointer specified